# ActionBar Icon doesn't appear on ActionBar again after setVisible to false then true

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have an ActionBar with mode `ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS`, I want to change icons which appear on ActionBar when I choose different tabs.

I did it successfully with an Activity, but it acted weird when I applied it again on another Activity.

Let's say I have 2 tabs: Tab1 and Tab2, and I want a Camera icon to appear when Tab2 is being chosen and disappear when Tab1 is being chosen. Moreover, Tab1 is the first tab will be chosen when the activity start.
So I did something like this:

Because I don't want the camera icon to appear at the first time HomeActivity start, so I set `android:visible="false"`, then when I run below code: when HomeActivity starts, camera icon doesn't appear on ActionBar -> correct, but when I switch to tab2, camera icon doesn't appear on ActionBar too, but if I press "Menu" button -> a MenuItem which is "Camera" appears as an overflow actionbar item.

And if I set `android:visible="true"` -> except the camera icon appears at the first time first time HomeActivity start (incorrect!!!) -> then camera icon disappears/appears correctly when I change tab1/tab2.

Can anyone explain and give me a solution to make it works correctly.
Thanks!

This is my code:

actionbar_home.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/actionbar_home_camera"
        android:title="@string/actionbar_rc_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_camera"
        android:showAsAction="always" 
        android:visible="false"/>
</menu>
```

HomeActivity.java

```
public class HomeActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
private ActionBar actionBar;
private Menu menu;
private Tab1Fragment tab1Fragment;
private Tab2Fragment tab2Fragment;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    this.configActionBar();
    this.createTabs();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actionbar_home, menu);
    this.menu = menu;

    // pass objects to tabs
    tab1Fragment.setOptionMenu(this.menu);
    tab2Fragment.setOptionMenu(this.menu);

    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void configActionBar()
{
    actionBar = this.getSupportActionBar();
    // below line makes application icon in top-left corner become a button
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    // below line add an arrow "<" before the top-left icon
    //ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    //actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
}

private void createTabs()
{
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    ActionBar.Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText(
            Const.TAB_TITLE_HOME_TAB1);
    ActionBar.Tab tab2 = actionBar.newTab().setText(
            Const.TAB_TITLE_HOME_TAB2);

    // create the two fragments we want to use for display content
    tab1Fragment = new Tab1Fragment();
    tab2Fragment = new Tab2Fragment();        

    // add listener
    tab1.setTabListener(
            new HomeTabListener(tab1Fragment));
    tab2.setTabListener(
            new HomeTabListener(tab2Fragment));        
    actionBar.addTab(tab1);
    actionBar.addTab(tab2);     
}
}
```

BaseTabFragment.java

```
public class BaseTabFragment extends SherlockFragment{
    protected View root;
    protected Menu optionMenu;
    protected SherlockFragmentActivity container;

    public Menu getOptionMenu() {
        return optionMenu;
    }
    public void setOptionMenu(Menu optionMenu) {
        this.optionMenu = optionMenu;
    }
    public SherlockFragmentActivity getContainer() {
        return container;
    }
    public void setContainer(SherlockFragmentActivity container) {
        this.container = container;
    }
}
```

Tab1Fragment.java

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends BaseTabFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_layout, 
                container, false);


        this.changeActionBarLayout();

        return root;
    }

    private void changeActionBarLayout()
    {
        try {
            this.optionMenu.findItem(R.id.actionbar_home_camera)
                .setVisible(false);
        } catch (NullPointerException e)
        {
            // e will be thrown at the first time MainActivity is called
        }       
    }
}
```

Tab2Fragment.java

```
public class Tab2Fragment extends BaseTabFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2_layout, 
                container, false);


        this.changeActionBarLayout();

        return root;
    }

    private void changeActionBarLayout()
    {
        try {
            this.optionMenu.findItem(R.id.actionbar_home_camera)
                .setVisible(true);
        // Camera Icon still doesn't appear on ActionBar even when I set it as SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS
        this.optionMenu.findItem(R.id.actionbar_home_camera)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        } catch (NullPointerException e)
        {
            // e will be thrown at the first time MainActivity is called
        }       
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some investigation, I think this is a bug, but I don't know it's ActionBarSherlock's bug or Android ActionBar's bug.

**Reason**

The reason is because of there's ONLY ONE MenuItem in option menu, let's say the MenuItem is mItem. When I set `mItem.setVisible(false)`, there will be no item left on ActionBar, then apparently, the space which contains ActionBar MenuItems is removed. After that, when I set `mItem.setVisible(true)`, the space is not restored, in that case, my `mItem` is considered as an overflow MenuItem -> it's only revealed when use Menu hardware button of devices.

**Solution**

- Use more than one MenuItem
- Subtly, use combination of `setEnable(false)` and `setIcon(null)` and `setTitle("")` instead of `setVisible(false)`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and found an easy solution for it: Just implement onPreparePanel in your Activity and return true even if all items are invisible.

```
public class HomeActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    [...]

    @Override
    public boolean onPreparePanel(int featureId, View view, Menu menu) {
        super.onPreparePanel(featureId, view, menu); // this returns false if all items are hidden
        return true; // return true to prevent the menu's deletion 
    }

    [...]

}
```

Comment: Nice one! Works for me. @LeoLink's solution is good, but setTitle("") causes extra space to be allocated and displayed and this leads to progress bar appear shifted to the left. Reimplementing onPreparePanel() does not have such drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and solved in this way:

Firstly I save the com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu when onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu ( Menu menu )
{
    ShowOrEditTaskActivity.this.getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.edit_or_show_task_menu, menu);
    setOptionsMenu ( menu );
    optionsMenu.findItem ( R.id.save_action ).setVisible ( false );
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu ( menu ) ;
}
```

Then  I check in every

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected ( MenuItem item )
```

call like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected ( MenuItem item )
{
    if ( item.getItemId ( ) ==   R.id.edit_action  )
    {
        isEditMode ( true ) ;
        optionsMenu.findItem ( R.id.edit_action ).setVisible ( false );
        optionsMenu.findItem ( R.id.save_action ).setVisible ( true );
    }...
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found out that `setVisible(true)` works when there is at least another `MenuItem` visible. I hope this can be helpful to someone.